# How to manage CORS in Django

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, axios

Im trying to connect React.js[axios] and Django [hosting in Heroku] and every time I get this.
On my localhosts everything works fine I get all the object except images, but all works fine.
[image]

Ive allowed my host to connect but it doesn't work

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGINS = [
    'localhost',
    'https://itbookcom.herokuapp.com/'
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'localhost',
    'https://itbookcom.herokuapp.com/'
]
```

and here is react.js connection part

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            bookList: [],
            error: null,
        };
    }
    refreshList = () => {
        axios
            .get('https://itbookcombackend.herokuapp.com/api/books/')
            .then((res) => this.setState({ bookList: res.data }))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshList();
    }
```

[GitHub - Front-End][2]
[2]: https://github.com/namra004/ITBooK

[GitHub - Back-End][3]
[3]:https://github.com/namra004/ITBookBackEnd

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-enable-cors-headers-in-your-django-project/)

Comment: Didn’t help me, anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow all for debugging case(DO NOT use this at production):
In your View you can add this

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
```

In settings.py

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Comment: and what to do for production then?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and resolved it successfully. I wrote a step-by-step blog regarding the same. Here is the link you can refer to.

Whenever there is a CORS origin Header issue, it simply means that the server and client are not known to each other (unknown request sent to the server).

For resolving this issue you can use the following steps

```
pip install django-cors-headers // this will install cors header package
```

Add/Update this in you setting files

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1','localhost','your_domain']
```

And in the django middleware file section add the below code

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
...
```

]

By doing this the issue would be resolved.

It is mostly due to the CORS origin blockage for security purposes.

Comment: Instead of (or as well as) linking to an external location, please provide your solution in the answer.

Comment: @andrewJames sure I have updated and will take care of it onwards. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try whitelisting the origin

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'localhost',
    'https://itbookcom.herokuapp.com/'
]
```

Comment: didn't work for me